# NSObject to React-Native object

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

If I have an NSObject defined:

```
// Person.h
@interface Person : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *uuid;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *firstName;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *lastName;
@end
```

... and I want to provide an array of `Person`s to my `ReactPeopleView`, how do I pass the `Person` objects to my react view?

When I try:

```
NSArray *people = [PeopleManager getAllPeople]; // returns an array of People objects
NSDictionary *properties = @{"people":people};
RCTRootView *root = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:_bridge
                                     moduleName:@"ReactPeopleView"
                              initialProperties:properties];
```

... the result is:

```
Running application "ReactPeopleView" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{"people":[]}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
```

where `'people':[]` is there, but it doesn't get any of the objects. I'm 100% they are there in the array before passing to react (I can see them in NSLog in the NSArray, `people`.

I'm very new to react-native, been playing with it for a few weeks. Been coding with ObjC for about 10 years. Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE 2016-08-30:**
I traced the instantiation of the react view all the way to `-(void)_executeJSCall:arguments:callback:` ... the arguments I pass in are correct the entire way there, so I'm not sure where things are getting lost.

**UPDATE 2016-08-31:**
I ended up just adding a `-(NSDictionary *)toDictionary;` function to each of my NSObject classes. Converting them that way before sending them to ReactPeopleView seems to be working; though no ideal. Anyone with a better solution please share :)